# What is this scaling operation called?

Tags: terminology

We have values representing measurements stored inside a grid and they range between [0,1].  These measurements are degraded using following formula

$$\text{measurement} =  \text{measurement} / (1 + \text{degradation factor}) $$

Degradation factor is usually between $(0,1)$

What is this operation called ? And does it have any significance?

Comment: it's the same as multiplying by a number between 0.5 and 1, so maybe just scaling by that?

Comment: is degradation factor static or is it calculated somehow?

Comment: @ZirconCode Degradation factor is static

Comment: @ZirconCode Yes it is doing some scaling as you said. But not sure whether it has any significance.

Comment: I think it has none other than making the scale fit better with other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$M = \frac{M}{1+d} = M \frac{1}{1+d}$

and $d \in (0,1) \implies 1+d \in (1,2) \implies \frac{1}{1+d} \in (0.5,1)$

thus we are simply scaling, "stretching", "squishing" by a little bit, probably to make it fit with other data. The scale is simply changed a little. Everything but the magnitude is left intact, even the proportion of one point to another remains. I think scaling is correct, or down-scaling since it can only remain the same or get smaller.